# qTip2 wrong position issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, qtip, qtip2

Basically I've just started using qTip2 (installed through the nugget package manager) in my asp.net MVC4 project.
Here's my BundleConfig:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/custom").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/CustomScripts/*.js",
                        "~/Scripts/libs/qtip2/jquery.qtip.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                "~/Content/site.css",
                "~/Content/libs/qtip2/jquery.qtip.css"));
            }
```

As you see I've included both

```
"~/Scripts/libs/qtip2/jquery.qtip.js"
```

and

```
"~/Content/libs/qtip2/jquery.qtip.css"
```

My _Layout.cshtml looks the following:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/custom")
</head>
```

My scripts folder looks the following:

[image]

And finally here's the actual implementation:
Called in ~/bundles/custom:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.submitbutton').qtip(
    {
        content: 'Some basic xcontent for the tooltip'
    });
});
```

And the actual submit button that should contain the tooltip:

```
<div class="buttons">
    <input class="submitbutton" type="submit" value="Register">
</div>
```

When I load the page I see the text when I move my mouse over the textbox - the issue is however that it's in the bottom left corner no matter what.

As seen in the image below:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

if you want the qtip to be on the middle top you should have the following in your Javascript initialization of qtip:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.submitbutton').qtip(
    {
        content: 'Some basic xcontent for the tooltip',
        position: {
                my: 'bottom center',  // tooltips tip at bottom center...
                at: 'top center', // in relation to the button's top center...
                target: $('.submitbutton') // my target
                  }
     });
});
```

note: all the positions can be found here: http://qtip2.com/options#position

Answer (score 0):

I know what you did, because I did it too. 
You forgot to include the corresponding qtip css.

Lesson: always check the browser's network traffic tab.